# How to query into LUIS programmatically

Tags: c#, azure-language-understanding

By default this is how can we send text to LUIS for processing and returns intents.

```
    [Serializable]
    public class LuisDialogController : LuisDialog<FAQConversation>
    {
        private readonly BuildFormDelegate<FAQConversation> _newConversation;

        public LuisDialogController(BuildFormDelegate<FAQConversation> newConversation) : base(new LuisService(new LuisModelAttribute(
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAppId"],
            ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIKey"],
            domain: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["LuisAPIHostName"])))
        {
            this._newConversation = newConversation;
        }

        [LuisIntent("None")]
        public async Task NoneIntent(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
        {
            await this.ShowLuisResult(context, result);
        }
}
```

I am wondering how can I send text to LUIS programmatically.

```
//pseudocode
var foo = new Luis();
var luisIntent = foo.processLanguage("How are you?");
switch(luisIntent)
{
   case LuisIntent.Inquiry:
   {
       //do something; break;
   }
   default:
   {
       //do something else; break;
   }
}
```

I've been looking in this [solution](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4361), however he did not answer by giving a regex.

Would the idea be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In publish section of your LUIS model you have "Resources and Keys" subsection [image]

Below "Endpoint" column you have url(s) that may be used to retrieve data from LUIS by http GET:

```
https://*.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/luis/v2.0/apps/
*?subscription-key=*&verbose=true&timezoneOffset=0&q=this%20is%20test%20sentence
```

It will provide you JSON result with structure similar to this:

```
{
  "query": "this is test sentence",
  "topScoringIntent": {
    "intent": "None",
    "score": 0.522913933
  },
  "intents": [
    ...
  ],
  "entities": []
}
```

See [more detail and sample C# code here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/luis/luis-get-started-cs-get-intent).

Alternatively you may use:

```
    using Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Luis;
    ...
    var model = new LuisModel() {};
    var luisService = new LuisService(model);
    var result = await luisService.QueryAsync(textToAnalyze, CancellationToken.None);
```